# How to simulate source routing in Mininet?

Tags: mininet, sdn

Is it possible to simulate source routing in an SDN with `Mininet`?

I want to put the path information in the packet itself and route it through the network.

Answer (score 0):

I think OVS switches used in Mininet have MPLS label match field implemented. 
Ref:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openvswitch/ovs/master/OPENFLOW-1.1+
https://www.opennetworking.org/images/stories/downloads/sdn-resources/onf-specifications/openflow/openflow-spec-v1.1.0.pdf

As such, ERO ,used in LSP creation, can be "implemented" in the controller application, as an emulation for source routing. (ERO with RSVP is really not needed in SDN, as the controller has the full picture) E.g. calculate path in controller using SPF or explicit, add MPLS label match with action to nodes on path that forwards packets in that flow to the next hop node.

I might misunderstand you, but you don't need path information on the packet. Just a tuple with match fields in the forwarding tables. The path information lies on the controller.